# Can you turn AC into DC through a Spark Gap?

Tags: ac, dc, spark

Is it possible to convert AC to DC using a spark gap as the medium, if so, could you provide a diagram?

Comment: It is kind of unclear what you want to achieve. Could you explain it with a little more details?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an electrician, so it's kind of hard for me to understand this...But I'd like to turn an AC power into a DC from electrode A to electrode B.

Comment: A diode (or more than one) would be a better solution. You want to look into a circuit called a "bridge rectifier," though be careful, as it can be dangerous working with high voltages

Comment: @ZaneKaminski
Interesting. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but you'll need a very special spark gap:

[image]

This is a [mercury arc rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-arc_valve), in other words an oldskool thyristor.

A real spark gap, like this one, is usually symmetrical, which means both electrodes are somewhat the same.

[image]

But... if you want to turn AC into DC, that is to rectify it, then you want it to conduct current in one direction, but not in the other direction. So it can't be symmetrical, there has to be something in its construction that makes it conduct when voltage is one polarity, and not conduct when voltage is the other polarity. A spark gap is pretty dumb, it's just gas between electrodes, and when there is enough electric field (ie, voltage) the gas gets ionized, becomes conductive, and current flows. There is no mechanism in there to only allow current to flow in one direction ; gas molecules have no idea of direction anyway, so it can't be used to rectify.

So the solution is to add an extra trigger electrode (the small pin in the middle):
[image]

In normal use, distance between the two large electrodes is enough so the gas doesn't get ionized and nothing happens. But if a high voltage pulse is applied to the trigger, then the gas gets ionized, and current flows. It will keep flowing until the gas de-ionizes and becomes an insulator again, which will happen only when current stops flowing. So it's possible to turn it on, but not possible to turn it off. This is not a problem with AC as the current goes to zero twice per period, so it'll turn itself off eventually. So... this triggered spark gap is pretty much like a thyristor or a triac. It's basically a switch, so if it is triggered with the proper timing, then it can be used to make a controlled rectifier.

The tiny one in the picture wouldn't last very long because the spark would melt the electrodes quickly, which is why triggered spark gap rectifiers use mercury electrodes: it's already a liquid, so it doesn't care about melting.

Now, these days, semiconductors are a lot more convenient and less toxic. So the answer to your question is most likely "just use diodes". Unless you want to rectify the output of a nuclear powerplant to send it over 1000km long high voltage DC line, in which case mercury arc rectifiers still seem to be a competitive option.

Comment: theses days optically triggered SCRs offer better performance at high power levels.  but I'm sure there are some thyratrons still in use somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rotary spark gap to rectify AC into DC. This is how in early years was made. But it is rather a complex setup:

- 1st you need is a step up transformer. Neon sign transformer may be used, approx 7kV
- You need a synchronous machine that you start up and synchronize with network. This coud be a coupled induction motor for start and then switched to a PMSM motor. For very small gap, you could also partially grind the rotor of the IM, it would rotate at synchronous speed but it would have almost no torque, making the IM t be useless for any other use.
- You need a disk of gaps
- You have to stay away, lethal voltage.

https://youtu.be/uTOlAwq1Hz4

[image]